# Use countif and left

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have the below code, is it possible to improve it by using as countif and left?

```
Sub leading_zeros()

    For Each Cell In Range("B:B")

        If Left(cell.value,1) = 0 Then

            MsgBox "This files has lines with leading zeros, once saved rename the file .csv"

            Exit Sub

        End If

        Next Cell


End Sub
```

Comment: By `improve` do you mean make it more efficient? Depending on your data one way might be to sort `B:B` first so that any cells with a leading zero appear at the start and therefore requires only one check rather than looping?

Comment: Hi, yes I did, I've managed to resolve my problem as below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub leading_zeros()

If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("I:I"), "0*") <> 0 Then

MsgBox "This files has lines with leading zeros, once saved rename the 
file .csv"

else

end if